# Powershell TRIM() is removing extra character

Tags: powershell, trim

I'm attempting to remove the "\MOSS2013" instance name from my SQL Server instance "WSFCSQLN1\MOSS2013"

**This works:**

```
$primaryReplicaGEN = $wsfcsqln2.AvailabilityGroups.PrimaryReplicaServerName
$primaryReplica = $PrimaryReplicaGEN.TRIM("\GEN")
```

$primaryReplica shows WSFCSQLN1

$primaryReplicaGEN shows WSFCSQLN1\GEN

**This does not work:**

```
$primaryReplicaMOSS2013 = $wsfcsqln1MOSS2013.AvailabilityGroups.PrimaryReplicaServerName
$primaryReplica = $PrimaryReplicaMOSS2013.TRIM("\MOSS2013")
```

$primaryReplica shows WSFCSQLN

$primaryReplicaMOSS2013 shows WSFCSQLN1\MOSS2013

Notice the replica name is missing the 1 at the end even though I did not choose to trim it. Why is it trimming the 1 for this particular string object? How can I force it to trim the correct characters.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Trim()` turns the string argument into a `[char[]]` and removes any of those characters from both ends of the string.

If you just want to grab the server name, use the `-split` operator and then discard the instance name:

```
$ServerName = 'WSFCSQLN1\MOSS2013' -split '\\' |Select-Object -First 1
```

or

```
$ServerName,$null = 'WSFCSQLN1\MOSS2013' -split '\\'
```

Answer (score 2):

well, thats how trim works, it will remove all the occurrences of all the characters you are going to trim which it can get to.

```
"agababga".Trim("ag")
```

would return `bab` not `ababga`, notice it didn't trim `a` inside `bab` as it cannot trim `b`, if you do:

```
"agababga".Trim("agb")
```

you would get nothing (empty string) in response

Answer (score 2):

you can use convertfrom-string too like this

```
$SplitedVar='WSFCSQLN1\MOSS2013' | ConvertFrom-String -Delimiter "\\" -PropertyNames "Domain", "ServerName"
$SplitedVar.Domain
$SplitedVar.ServerName
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd use a **split** call:

```
$primaryReplica = $PrimaryReplicaGEN.split('\')[0];
```